# Resize an image to multiple resolutions simultaneously

Tags: linux, windows, images, software-rec

I am looking for software (Windows or Linux) that can do the following:

- Resize one image to several provided sizes.
- Detects the type of the pic­ture (wide, nor­mal) and does the resize based on that. What I mean by that is that it should not break the image by shrinking it more in one direction then in the other so it looks weird.

The purpose of this is my Blog. If I want to give my readers a wallpaper, I want to give them several options for the sizes so they can have it in their own preferred screen resolution. The image must however keep its original aspect ratio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: GIMP has options for scripting and you can re-size and keep ratios. It will have a bit of a learning curve to get it working, but it is a very customizable and powerful option for what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Convert command in ImageMagick will do what you want, too, and it's perhaps more suited to use in a script (since it has no GUI components to load). which is seemingly what you want. You can easily resize photos while keeping the aspect ratio, for instance by specifying a width only, or a height only.

Comment: I am using PHP to make a script to resize images I upload to the script with ImageMagick. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

@MaQleod is correct.  GIMP will do exactly what you want and it's free.  He is also correct regarding the learning curve.  If you are more familiar with Adobe's Photoshop product (not free), it can get your task done as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this works in GIMP? (E.g. which options do you need, how can you automate this?)

Comment: GIMP's image processing functions use Scheme (http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Scheme/).  More information regarding incorporating batch functionality can be found @ http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/.  A tutorial which incorporates both including other image filtering can be found @ http://drupalique.com/story/2011-02-02/gimp-batch-image-processing-auto-color-enhance-levels-resize-and-save.